# Heat equation: Why are these ratios of functions constant

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

One can solve the heat equation 
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} =  \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$
by a separation of variables such that $u(x, t) = f(x)g(t)$.

Substituting this into the equation yields
$$
\frac{f''(x)}{f(x)}
 = \frac{\dot g(t)}{g(t)} = c$$
for some constant $c$.

My question is: why are these ratios constant? I just can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the left hand side depends only on $x$ while the right hand side depends only on $t$. The two quantities are equal no matter what choice of $x,t$ you choose. We deduce that the quantities are constant, because that is precisely how you define a constant function; a function that returns the same value everywhere, regardless of choice of input.